# Recommendation for advanced CMS with LDAP support

Tags: content-management-system, ldap

I'm developing and designing a site for a customer. I would like to give him some control over content but also allow myself control over the outputted code/graphic.

Normally for simple sites, I am using toko cms (content editor), but for this site i need something more advanced with database and user sync (LDAP).

Any recommendations ? Maybe a robust but productive framework?

Comment: what language are you writing in?

Comment: @Hunter, +1, please specify the language!

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal](http://drupal.org) has an [LDAP module](http://drupal.org/project/ldap_integration), and is generally a good solid CMS.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get lots of recommendations to a question quite as open-ended as that.

`<mild_sarcasm>`
Me, I absolutely know that the correct answer to all questions involving what framework to use is [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com).
`</mild_sarcasm>`

If you need LDAP support, there's [django-ldap-groups](http://code.google.com/p/django-ldap-groups/).

Note that Django itself is not a CMS, it's a framework for building "content management systems" (whatever you mean by that term).

Answer (score 0):

[Concrete5](https://www.concrete5.org/) has a [package](https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/exchangecore-ldap-authentication) available for LDAP integration.